# Cache assets of YII in browser

Tags: yii

I am finding all assets and images are being downloaded by GET request again on each page refresh in Yii 1.* series.

How can we start using browser cache so that modular assets and other static are not always downloaded ?

I have already commented following in index.php

```
//defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup Apache or the web server that you use, to have the browser cache enabled for the `/assets` folder (or the entire website). This is a [great tutorial](http://kuppalli.wordpress.com/2009/07/14/apache-configuration-for-etags-gzip-and-expires-header/) to help you out.

Then you should: **Symlink your assets**

You can improve its performance slightly by using symbolic links instead of file copies. In order to turn it on you should configure linkAssets property of assetManager application component using protected/config/main.php config file:

```
return array(
    // ...
    'components' => array(
        // ...
        'assetManager' => array(
            'linkAssets' => true,
        ),
    ),
);
```

Note that it may require [additional configuration](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CAssetManager#linkAssets-detail).